# Laravel 419 page expire error at /broadcasting/auth, but csrfToken is added LARAVEL NOTIFICATIONS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, pusher, laravel-echo

Laravel 7

I am trying to add Laravel Notification in my project but stuck at listening notifications, mostly getting errors at broadcasting/auth I have solved this issue once but still not getting notification here is my code

App\Notifications\MessageReceived

```
class MessageReceived extends Notification
{

    use Queueable;



    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 *
 */

public $notification;

public function __construct($notify)
{
    //
    $this->notification=$notify;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */


public  function toDatabase($notifiable){

    return [
        'MessageSender'=>$this->notification,
    ];
}



public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'MessageSender'=>$this->notification,
    ];
}

public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
{
    return new BroadcastMessage([
        'MessageSender'=>$this->notification,
    ]);
}
```

my custom guard. Admin Model

```
    class Admin extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;
    
        protected $guard = 'admin';
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password',
        ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
    {

        return 'admin.'.$this->id;
    }
}
```

route/channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {

    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('App.Admin.{id}', function ($admin, $id) {

    return (int) $admin->id === (int) $id;
},['guards' => ['admin']]);
```

public/js/listner.js (i am using this js file link below the link of js/app.js file and its working i have tested it)

```
Echo.private('App.Admin.${id}' )
    .notification((notification) =>{
        window.alert(notification.type)
        console.log(notification)
    });
```

controller method which is triggering notification

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }
        
        $admin = Admin::find(1);
       $admin->notify(new MessageReceived($request->email));


        return response()->json([
            'success'=>'Message sent successfully. we will get to you soon as possible',
//            'data'=>$noty,
        ], 200);
    }
```

resource/js/boostrap.js

```
 import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    authEndpoint: "/broadcasting/auth",
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
                },
                },
    // csrfToken:document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
});
window.Pusher.log = function(message ,err){
  console.log(message);
  console.log(err)
}
```

this is all of my code but still, I am not able to listen to my triggered notification,
my env file have all of values correct like BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher and pusher keys etc

need some guide about this where i am wrong and what should i do to make this work

Comment: i also unComment the broadcastServiceProviders for broadcasting

Answer (score 1):

The via method in your Notification class should return `['broadcast']`.

Also remove `use Queueable;` trait from your Notifications class.

Don't forget to add `namespace` property in your `Pusher` initializer as `App.Events`.

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    authEndpoint: "/broadcasting/auth",
    namespace: 'App.Events'
});
```